# How to show the relationships in Visual Studio class diagram

Tags: visual-studio, class-diagram

I have a class library with few interfaces and the implementing classes categorized in different folders. I have generated the class diagrams of the interfaces in the project, but not able to see the relationships to the classes derived from these.
When i try to choose "Show Derived Interfaces" from the context menu of the interface, i get the below error:

[image]

Though in the same folder there are classes which are implemented from that interface.

Thanks in advance for any hint in finding the correct way.

Any hint on how to establish manual relationships between the interfaces and classes would also help. I have tried from the Toolbox -> Inheritance option, but not could not do it.

I am using Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition

**Correction**: I am able to create the relationships manually (from the Toolbox -> Inheritance option) between classes and its base class type.The problem i see when i try to draw the relationship from the class to its base interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue:

[image]

I notice your metioned:

> Though in the same folder there are classes which are implemented from
> that interface.

But the feature 'Show Derived Interfaces' will not pass focus to the class, but to pass focus to the interface.

[image]

Comment: Okay, now i get the meaning of "Show Derived Interfaces", also justifies literally; thanks for demonstrating this for me. But i wonder then what's there to show the Interface->Class relationships then?

Comment: @Pankaj_Sen If you mean the focus/line during the class and interface, I think currently the answer is **NO**, as you can see this feature doesn't have two many operations. But there is a white lollipop shape around the interface, it can tell you what class implement this interface. :)

Comment: @Pankaj_Sen If you have some ideas/feature requests, you can share your ideas/feature request to this place: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/suggest. This is official feedback place of Visual Studio Tool.

Comment: yes i have seen that lollipop shape at the top of the implemented class, which also can be expanded (shape right click -> expand) to see the name of its base interface; it helps somewhat but the base interface box stays as orphan. Anyway maybe i am trying to compare it with other UML tools. Microsoft has kept it this way to save some space for bigger diagrams maybe, not sure :)....anyways thanks for your link to suggest the idea to MS....and thanks a lot for your kind answers, at least got to know that there are no such ways how i wanted it to be.